# Given a float, find if in list or closest number to it

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples, namely 2-dim tuples with values of x and y. Call it data. I want to take two floats, xmin and xmax, and return the index of the maximum y value on that interval. 
It should also work even if xmin and xmax don’t match the data points exactly.

I understand how to do the problem except a way to round xmin and xmax to the closest values on the list. I have no idea as I'm a python newbie.

```
# Find the index of the point (x, y) with the maximum y value
# on the interval [xmin, xmax]
def find_peak(data, xmin, xmax):
```

Tentatively, I can search through the list and record the smallest difference for each x-value. Would that be feasible or is there a smarter way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a list of 2 dimensional coordinates .

1. Sort the data based on x-coordinate. This should be natural list sort.
2. Use python [bisect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to determine the start and end index of the data points
3. Use the built-in `min` with key as `operator.itemgetter(1)` to find the element within x_main and x_max with maximum y-value

**Sample Implementation**

```
def foo(data, x_min, x_max):
    from bisect import bisect_left, bisect
    from operator import itemgetter
    data = sorted(data)
    x_data = [x for x,y in data]
    index_min = bisect_left(x_data, x_min)
    index_max = bisect(x_data, x_max)
    return max(data[index_min:index_max],key=itemgetter(1))[-1]
```

**Example Run**

```
>>> data = [(random.randint(1,20),random.randint(1,20)) for _ in range(10)]
>>> data
[(9, 9), (11, 11), (7, 7), (16, 11), (15, 19), (8, 18), (16, 3), (18, 7), (17, 13), (3, 11)]
>>> foo(data,3,7)
11
```

Comment: What is this operation?

    x_data = [x for x,y in data]

Comment: @alvarezcl: This is a list comprehension. This will return a list with all the x-coordinates within the data points. Unfortunately bisect module do not have a custom key feature, so you have to add that extra over-head. But, remember, even with the overhead, this implementation would be quite fast, considering the Order of Complexity is O(nlog(n)) and there is no overhead in any complex calculation.

Comment: The code in this answer raises `ValueError` if `xmax` is smaller than the smallest `x` value in `data`. The `return` statement should be nested in a `try` statement.

Answer (score 2):

```
max_finder = lambda point: point[1] if x_min <= point[0] <= x_max else float("-inf")
# get data point of target element
max_y = max(data, key=max_finder)

# gets index of target element
max_y_idx = max(enumerate(data), key=lambda x: max_finder(x[1]))[0]
# or alternatively, after finding max_y
max_y_idx = data.index(max_y_idx)
```

Note that this should slightly outperform sorting variants as `max` have O(n) complexity and `index` have O(n) worst-case complexity, compared to O(n*log(n)) sort complexity.

Refer to [max](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) and [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) documentation for details